coreui - How do I create a Logout link (with icon) at the footer (CSidebarFooter) of the sidebar properly ? (in React) Collapse/Expand issue
In coreui for React, How do I create a Logout link (with icon) at the footer of the sidebar properly ? (in React) I want so that when sidebar expanded, it should have icon and text. and when side bar is contracted, only the icon. This same thing I want to also work with the CSidebarHeader as well.
https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template <-- this is the template I'm using. You can easily run it and test it out.
I tried the following (location here https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template/blob/main/src/components/AppSidebar.js):
  <CSidebarFooter className="border-top d-none d-lg-flex">
    
  <CNavItem customClassName="nav-icon">
    <CNavLink to='/logout'>
      <CIcon icon={cilAccountLogout} className="me-2" />
      Logout
    </CNavLink>
  </CNavItem>
  
    <CSidebarToggler
      onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'set', sidebarUnfoldable: !unfoldable })}
    />
  </CSidebarFooter>

But if you check out the screenshots. There is a dot and when the sidebar is contracted, the word "Logout" doesnt disappear.


UPDATE (I tried another way, no dot, but the collapse didnt disappear the text :
 <CSidebarFooter style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}>
     
        <CIcon icon={cilAccountLogout} height={20} />
        <div style={{fontSize: 15 }}> Logout</div>
      

    <CSidebarToggler
      onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'set', sidebarUnfoldable: !unfoldable })}
    />        
  </CSidebarFooter>



UPDATE:
I even tried to find a way to detect when the sidebar collapse. https://gist.github.com/axilaris/9a5f4b6a0c2b7d54edb157c3e5c9e304. But this will only detect when it totally collapse. still cant get it.

Can you post the rendered HTML? Honestly, that dot looks a lot like a <ul> dot. I wonder if it's a <ul> that's missing CSS list-style:none;

....Building on that, I'm guessing CNavItem is probably an <li>, which is why we're getting this in the first place, but I'm surprised that CoreUI's default CSS doesn't automatically add list-style:none;. You ARE getting most CSS styles from CoreUI, right? Otherwise this'd be a very different post. (Sometimes we see this happen when a dev forgets to import the CSS file, if there's a separate one, but in that case none of CoreUI would appear correctly.)

Maybe the CSS primarily comes from CNavGroup, and so you'd need to add a CNavGroup to get the CSS to hide the dot, and style it properly.

I put in an update, removed the CNavItem and CNavLink. No dot but collapse doesnt disappear the text. https://imgur.com/a/nXgFi1F

// AppSidebar.js

    <CSidebar>

    {/* Rest of the SideBar components */}

      <AppSidebarNav items={navigation} />

      <CSidebarFooter>
        <CSidebarNav>
          <CNavItem href="#">
            <CIcon customClassName="nav-icon" icon={cilAccountLogout} />
            Logout
          </CNavItem>
        </CSidebarNav>

        <CSidebarToggler
          onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'set', sidebarUnfoldable: !unfoldable })}
        />
      </CSidebarFooter>
    </CSidebar>



Apparently, the CSidebarFooter is not meant to hold links. If you try the code above, the icon for the logout is hidden on collapse, and only the toggler icon is shown. Also, there's a different design problem from my perspective: The logout shouldn't share row with the collapsible.
How CoreUI resolves this problem is holding every NavItem inside a CSidebarHeader. This also preserves the icons when the sidebar is collapsed. This is already described in their examples.
With that said, maybe is a better solution to left the footer with just the toggler, and create a different section for the logout. Also it would be a good idea to use different icons for the toggle and the logout:
      <AppSidebarNav items={navigation} />
      <CSidebarHeader className="border-top">
        <CSidebarNav>
          <CNavItem href="#">
            <CIcon customClassName="nav-icon" icon={cilAccountLogout} />
            Logout
          </CNavItem>
        </CSidebarNav>
      </CSidebarHeader>

      <CSidebarFooter>
        <CSidebarToggler
          onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'set', sidebarUnfoldable: !unfoldable })}
        />
      </CSidebarFooter>



i think thats a good answer. I just need a little alignment, I still cant get it. the problem with the solution that it is not aligned with the other AppSidebarNav items. I tried to put some marginLeft. I got it aligned but when i click to collapse, it is not aligned again. https://gist.github.com/axilaris/5954e10e2b7b597815a56030f34feacc here is the screenshot of this: https://imgur.com/a/aSKB4gP

You are right @Axil, there's an small misalignment. The SidebarFooter has more padding that its siblings. It can be fixed by removing the left padding:
      <CSidebarFooter style={{ paddingLeft: 0 }}>
```. Or similar solution with the css framework of your choice

All the side bar manu options are defined in a _nav.js file as a list which is then passed on to the AppSidebarNav items=[] as an input. Thus the simplest way I found to do it is to reuse the tools provided:
I created in the same level as _nav.js _navFooter.js defining a single item in the list:
const _navFooter = [
  {
    component: CNavGroup,
    name: 'Loug out',
    to: '#',
    icon: <CIcon icon={cilAccountLogout} customClassName="nav-icon" />
  },
]

export default _navFooter

imported that into the AppSidebar and then defined my footer as follows:
  <CSidebarFooter>
    <AppSidebarNav items={footerNavigation} />
  </CSidebarFooter>

Hope this helps!
